# Generate an output from a sorted ascending array based on index

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, min

I want to generate an output using 2 different sets of arrays.

```
    int[] A = {7, 3, 8, 21, 5, 11};
    int[] B = {3, 5, 1};
```

Using a method, I want to sort array A but **not** array B to produce an output with the B[i]th value of the smallest number in array A.

For example, B[3] would equal to the 3rd smallest element of A which is 7.

Afterwards, I want to sort the output in ascending order, but I've figured that part out. I'm only having issues getting the right values from A.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
public static void Algorithm2(int[] A, int[] B) {
    sortOrder(A);
    
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    int min = A[0];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if(B[i] >= min) {
            result[i] = A[B[i] -1];
        }
    }
    
    sortOrder(result);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    
    /*
    A is [3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 21]
    B is [3, 5, 1]
    Desired output is [3, 7, 11] 
     */
}
```

So far, this is what I've come up with but I can't seem to figure out how to the correct values from A.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an output based on 2 different arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500675/how-to-get-an-output-based-on-2-different-arrays)

Comment: >For example, B[3] would equal to the 3rd smallest element of A which is 7.< B[3] doesn't exist. Allowing for the fact that you might mean B[2], I still don't know what you mean…

Comment: You haven't adequately explained the problems you are encountering.  Expected output.  Your output.  And a more descriptive narrative as to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

- first, sort A as stated.
- then stream the values of B and, subtracting one, index into the sorted version of A.
- Then sort the result.

```
Arrays.sort(A);
int[] result = Arrays.stream(B).map(i->A[i-1]).sorted().toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Prints

```
[3, 7, 11]
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to have a nested loop and go through both arrays, you simply need to loop through the `result.length` or `B.length` (as they are always equal) and take the value of `B[i] - 1` and use it as the index to access `A`. This leaves you with `result[i] = A[B[i] - 1]`.

**Fixed Code:**

```
public static void Algorithm1(int [] A, int [] B) {
    sortOrder(A);
    sortOrder(B);
    
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = A[B[i] - 1];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

**Test Run:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    
    int [] arr1 = new int[]{21, 8, 11, 7, 5, 3};
    int [] arr2 = new int[]{3, 5, 1};

    Algorithm1(arr1, arr2);
    
}
```

**Output:**

`[3, 7, 11]`